# Intercept all requests before a Controller Action is executed

Tags: authentication

Is there a way to intercept a request before a controller action is run, so that you could preform additional authorisation checks?

Say I have an authorised user, but their access to actions is dependant on a 3rd party API. So I need a way to check, this 3rd party API or a stored session version, before each action is performed.

I can see the `beforeAction()` method, which is fine for new Controllers I have added, but I need site wide solution that will catch request that go through Craft and doesn't touch any plugins.

I can see the `onBeginRequest` Event, but aware this fires before Craft has had chance to setup. So I feel this might not be the best solution for me, as I would like to use services inside custom plugins. If there is no other way, I assume this is best place to look. If so what is the best way to add an Event listener for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct about both `beforeAction()` and `onBeginRequest()`.

However, you could put an `init()` method in your main [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins) class file and this will execute on every request as long as the plugin is installed and enabled.

```
public function init()
{
    // Whatever code you were going to put in onBeginRequest can go here.
    parent::init();
}
```

Comment: I had considered this and even started to write code! However it made me feel like I was hacking at it, so I stopped. Thanks for letting us know that at present I wasn't far off the mark!